# Cant install dependencies Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, packagist

Trying to install dependencies:

```
{
"name": "whatever",
"description": "",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sirian/symfony-sphinx-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.*",
    "jms/serializer": "dev-master",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.1",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sirian/helpers": "dev-master",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "dev-master",
    "intervention/image": "1.*",
    "Chumper/Zipper": "dev-master",
    "sirian/symfony2-openexchangerates-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sirian/yandex-market-language-parser": "dev-master",
    "fresh/doctrine-enum-bundle": "v2.5",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "~2.0",
    "sirian/suggest-bundle": "dev-master",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "dev-master",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.0@dev",
    "maxmind-db/reader": "dev-master"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Here is error from console:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.34
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.33
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.32
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.31
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.30
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.29
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.28
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.27
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.26
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.25
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.24
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.23
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.22
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.21
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.20
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.19
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.18
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.17
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.16
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.15
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.14
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.13
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.12
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.10
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.8
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.7
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.6
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.5
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.4
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.3
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.2
- Installation request for vich/uploader-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by vich/uploader-bundle[dev-master].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
- vich/uploader-bundle dev-master requires symfony/property-access ~2.4|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev], symfony/property-access[2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, v2.4.0, v2.4.0-BETA1, v2.4.0-BETA2, v2.4.0-RC1, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-BETA1, v2.5.0-BETA2, v2.5.0-RC1, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.0-BETA1, v2.6.0-BETA2, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.8.0-BETA1, v3.0.0-BETA1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.4.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.5.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.6.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.7.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[3.0.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev].
- don't install symfony/property-access 2.4.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access 2.5.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access 2.6.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access 2.7.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access 2.8.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access 3.0.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.0-RC1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.0-RC1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v2.8.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- don't install symfony/property-access v3.0.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev
- Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.3.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9].
```

(Running windows 7)

Please help, what to do?

Comment: Hello! Next time you post, please do add all your code/logs on the message - questions should not depend on external resources.

Comment: Hey, CJ, could you please post a more detailed output? Like `composer update -vvv`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is in this log line:

```
vich/uploader-bundle dev-master requires symfony/property-access ~2.4|~3.0 
-> satisfiable by 
symfony/symfony[2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev], 
symfony/property-access[2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, v2.4.0, v2.4.0-BETA1, v2.4.0-BETA2, v2.4.0-RC1, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-BETA1, v2.5.0-BETA2, v2.5.0-RC1, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.0-BETA1, v2.6.0-BETA2, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.8.0-BETA1, v3.0.0-BETA1].
```

Simply put, you just need an updated version of symfony:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.4.*",
... //or newer
```

Comment: but what should I do when i can't change version of Symfony?

Comment: @CJSuspend Well, those two are not compatible. You can either change the version of Symfony or find a (probably older) version of `vich/uploader-bundle` that is compatible with 2.3 and change that.

Comment: those dependencies successfully install on ubuntu or another machines, but for mine - no.

Comment: Congratulations for having found the problem but I don't agree with your solution. Symfony 2.4 is outdated, you should suggest to install Symfony 2.7 instead.